# md5/crc64 issue after update app to API29

Tags: xamarin.android, android-10.0

I updated my app to using Android 10.0 SDK (29), removed all reference to Support Library and added AndroidX. Until now everything works great.

When I update my App (compiled by VS2017 API 28), all widgets display "Problem Loading Widget" and on main screen is added second app icon. User have to remove them and add all widgets again.

After many hours I found, that in AndroidManifest.xml was changed name of Activities, BroadcastReceivers... from md5*.MainActivity to crc64*.MainActivity. 
It confirms this [link](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/3844) about removing MD5 algorithm.
The functionality of my App is based on widgets. If I release the update, I'm pretty sure, that I will get many one star reviews that the App stopped working after update.

One ugly solution should be use the property Name in declaration widget receiver and pass there the name of receiver from AndroidManifest previous version.

```
[BroadcastReceiver( Name = md5*.AppWidget", ....)]
```

Is there any workaround to solve this issue?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yon can refer to this thread:https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/pull/3649 
 it say "The previous default can be restored via
$(AndroidApkSigningAlgorithm) and $(AndroidApkDigestAlgorithm)
MSBuild properties." Please open your project folder, found the `.csproj` file, you can see the `$(AndroidApkSigningAlgorithm) and $(AndroidApkDigestAlgorithm)`,please change `<PropertyGroup>
  <AndroidApkSigningAlgorithm>md5withRSA</AndroidApkSigningAlgorithm>
  <AndroidApkDigestAlgorithm>SHA1</AndroidApkDigestAlgorithm>
</PropertyGroup>`

Comment: Thanks, I will try it! It's true that it's works only for APK, not for App Bundle?

Comment: Is that worked as normal?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Into <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' "> I added packaging properties as you mentioned, but in final AndroidManifest.xml are my class names like crc64****.